# Why is QGIS not recognising altitude from CSV file?

Tags: qgis, raster, labeling, dem, altitude

I used the Google Earth method for creating a KML file of points with latitude, longitude, and altitude as necessary information. After that I converted the KML file to GPX and then to CSV, through the tcx converter. The converter returned the correct altitude expected for my region of study, but when the CSV file is opened in QGIS and used to generate a DEM through Natural Neighbor, everything goes wrong... The altitude is misread when the label is created -- the altitude should be at around 850 and is being read as 160...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the csv as text to your question so we can use to reproduce your results?

Comment: Good morning Shianne, and welcome to SE-GIS.  QGIS can load both kml and gpx files directly, so there's no need to convert them to a csv format just to get them into QGIS.  I wonder if something went astray during the kml -> gpx -> csv process?  It would really help if you could edit your question by adding the first few lines from each file format so that folks could watch the same data as it progressed from one format to another.